# Get ShortUrl using Mremi\UrlShortener from object - laravel

Tags: php, object, laravel-5, url-shortener

I know this looks quit simple, but I am unable to get this.

I want to generate short Url from a long-Url by using this [mremi UrlShortner](https://github.com/mremi/UrlShortener) , I have installed it using composer and using it like this as suggested by its developer, using Bitly

```
use Mremi\UrlShortener\Provider\Bitly\BitlyProvider;
use Mremi\UrlShortener\Provider\Bitly\OAuthClient;


$link = new Link;
$link->setLongUrl('https://files.slack.com/files-pri/TE01UKRJT-FJKP9KX39/image_from_ios.jpg');
$bitlyProvider = new BitlyProvider(
        new OAuthClient('**********', '**********'), // or new GenericAccessTokenAuthenticator('generic_access_token')
        array('connect_timeout' => 10, 'timeout' => 10)
    ); 
$bitlyProvider->shorten($link);
```

Short link is getting generated and when i print **$link** i get the response like this in Object. But im not understanding how to get the my **ShortUrl** from this.

Here is the response im getting.

```
Mremi\UrlShortener\Model\Link Object
(
[providerName:protected] => 
[shortUrl:protected] => 'getting my short url here'
[longUrl:protected] => https://files.slack.com/files-pri/TE01UKRJT-FJKP9KX39/image_from_ios.jpg
[createdAt:protected] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2019-05-10 11:42:41.168344
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => Asia/Calcutta
    )

 )
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get that **shortUrl:protected** from that object and store it in a new variable.

Im using lravel 5.4

Comment: That seems to be a [`Link`](https://github.com/mremi/UrlShortener/blob/master/src/Mremi/UrlShortener/Model/Link.php) object which seems to contain a method called `getShortUrl` you could call to get the short url

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry i didn't understood, can you please elaborate?

Comment: `return $bitlyProvider->shorten($link)->getShortUrl()`

Comment: Don't mind i have tried this already, it saya `Call to a member function getShortUrl() on null`, i passed $link also to that, then also its same.